# Neo4j cypher query for connected components is too slow

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am looking for help to optimize my following cypher query.

```
CALL algo.unionFind.stream()
YIELD nodeId,setId
MATCH(n) where ID(n) = nodeId AND NOT (n)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]-()
call apoc.create.uuids(1) YIELD uuid
WITH n as nod, uuid, setId
WHERE nod is not null
   MERGE(groupid:GroupId {group_id:'id_'+toString(setId)})
   ON CREATE set groupid.group_value = uuid, groupid.updated_at = '1512135348335'
   MERGE(nod)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->(groupid)
RETURN count(nod);
```

I have already applied the unique constraints and index over group_id. Even I am using a good configurations machine i3-2xl.
The above query is taking too long time ~22 minutes for ~500k nodes.

Following are the things I want to achieve from the above query.

1. Get all the connected components(sub-graph).
2. Create a new node for each group(connected components).
3. Assign uuid as a value of the new group node.
4. Build the relationship with all the group members with the new group node.

Any suggestions are welcome to optimize the above query, or please let me know if is there any other way to achieve my listed requirement.

Comment: Why you don't use the `algo.unionFind` procedure that directly write into a property the partition id ? It will be more faster. And why do you want to create a node for each partition ? An attribut or a label is not enought ?

Comment: @logisima before of stream(), I tried with unionFind() and use the partition to create a new node over the partition but it took the same time.

Comment: @logisima basically I want to identify all the connected nodes with a single node that's why creating a new node over each set and wanted to use that single node for further use.

Comment: To compute all the partitions of a graph is an expensive operation, and need to read your entire database (specially relationships). The graph algo is made to make a lot of parallel processing, but your CPU is only on i3

Comment: Do you have a typo in your `MATCH` clause? Since the `NOT (n)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]-()` pattern does not specify a relationship direction, it will filter out all `n` nodes that are either the child of or the parent of another node.

Comment: @cybersam actually this a single level relationship does not have any impact, but I have tried with `NOT (n)-[:IS_CHILD_OF]->()` and got the same response time.